# In TFS Releases, is there a way to execute powershell script befor downloading artifacts on same agent?

Tags: tfs, release

Problem:
We are running Selenium tests using release pipelines. If environment deployment which runs those tests is cancelled then the drivers might not be killed, and this will lock the working folder. So when the deployment happens again on same environment within the release definition (does not matter if it is new release or redeployment), release agent will throw the error that the working folder is locked.

So we do have powershell task with an inline script that does the clean up (it is inline so no dependencies), but unfortunately TFS release pipeline tries to download the artifacts into the locked folder before running mentioned powershell script.

Is there a way to execute an inline powershell before the release pipeline downloads the artifacts?

We do have a partial solution that uses multiple phases but this will only work as long a the deployment queue is not busy, and we are getting to the point where it will be in the future, and when queue is busy TFS might pick different agents for different phases of specific environment deployment, resulting in this approach not to work. So bonus question from this one: Alternatively, is possible to lock the agent for specific environment deployment so that agent does not change between phases?

I did searches for both solutions and it looks like there are no out of the box solutions, or did I miss one? if not then is there some creative way to achieve either of these?

Answer (score 2):

You're approaching this from the wrong end. If the process failed, **it needs to clean up**. Thus, add a task *at the end* of the release with a [condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=designer) of `canceled()` (or perhaps `ne(succeeded())` to perform your cleanup operations.

Also, you didn't specify what language you're doing your Selenium testing in, but in C# you can wrap your webdriver creation in a `using` block to ensure it properly cleans up the driver. There are ostensibly similar constructs or patterns in other languages. Basically, "if the web driver goes out of scope, clean it up, period".

Comment: I do have clean up in both code itself with Teardown method and pipeline with Posershell script, but I did not know about canceled () flag. If it works like I understand then it should solve my problem. TY.

Comment: I revoked the mark as a solution because cancled() flag is not available in release pipelines. It is available in the builds. I wonder why this feature is included with builds but not releases.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue with downloading artifact, you can disable this step by Click on the Environment name, expand  Additional options and then select "skip artifact download":

[image]

Comment: As I outlined in my inquiry, we already doing that. I belive @Danial-Mann answered my question. Thank you though anyway this might be useful for someone else.